# Python __getattribute__ with 'is-a'/'has-a' relation

Tags: python-3.x

Working with python3 I am a bit stumped on why `__getattribute__` isn't working with my class structure.
I googled around but could not understand why it won't work.

Here is the no-frills class structure, removing all that was not required:

```
class Platform:
  def execute(self):
    print("Calling execute in Platform")

class Host():
  def __init__(self):
    self.plat = Platform()

  def __getattr__(self, name):
    if name in dir(self):
      return self.__getattribute__(name)
    if name in dir(self.plat):
      return self.plat.__getattribute__(name)

class Connector(Host):
  pass

class LDAP():
  def __init__(self):
    self.conn = Connector()

  def __getattr__(self, name):
    return self.conn.__getattribute__(name)
```

I have a working object `ldp = LDAP()`. Calling `ldp.execute()` raises `AttributeError: 'Connector' object has no attribute 'execute'`

I would expect calling `ldp.execute()` would do the following:

- Call `__getattr__` from `LDAP` which calls `__getattribute__` on `Connector` object
- That would again call `__getattr__` on `Host` which would call `__getattribute__` on `Platform` object
- That would eventually call `execute` method from `Platform`

And ofcourse that isn't working as expected :)

If however, I call `self.conn.__getattr__(name)` from `__getattr__` in LDAP class, that works, maybe because I have `__getattr__` defined in Host.

What am I missing here ?

**Note: I can't modify the Platform and Host classes. Only Connector and LDAP are mine**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's generally a mistake to call `__getattribute__` directly. Instead, use the `getattr` builtin:

```
class LDAP():
  def __init__(self):
    self.conn = Connector()

  def __getattr__(self, name):
    return getattr(self.conn, name)
```

The `getattr` function knows to look for `__getattr__`, while `__getattribute__` does not.

Comment: Ah, yes I thought about using `getattr`, didn't try it though. Thinking that it will just raise `AttributeError` without calling `__getattr__` Isn't it the general rule that if `__getattribute__` can't find the attribute `__getattr__` is called before raising `AttributeError` ?